# Get images from MySQL to Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2-5 images in 1 post and I want to show all images of all posts when I click to Bootstrap modal.

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ALL IMAGES WILL SHOW HERE
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One solution might be to get the array of the image locations and then pass this array to your template. Now when dialog is triggered just load images from array using jquery by using `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Using jquery
```

=============

1. Give your modal launch button an id eg id="show"
2. Add the following jquery code to add your images to your modal

   ```
   $("#show").on("click", function() {$(".modal-body").html("<img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg' width='80px'><img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/51397/legs-window-car-dirt-road-51397.jpeg'  width='80px'><img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/21014/pexels-photo.jpg'  width='80px'>"    );  })
   ```

[View Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hx16r7s8/9/)